# Google AppEngine in android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I m new to GCM do u guys please guide me for using Google App Engine.

I want to create a signup page which registers details of users on Google server
to signup and logging the account

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) offering that lets you build and run applications on Google’s infrastructure. App Engine applications are easy to build, easy to maintain, and easy to scale as your traffic and data storage needs change. With App Engine, there are no servers for you to maintain. You simply upload your application and it’s ready to go.

For using App Engine you have to first download an appropriate sdk based on your development environment

[Download the Google App Engine SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads)

For working on a particular language

[Google App Engine Languages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)

Comment: yes it is possible https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/cloud-sql/application_with_local_mysql

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions a bunch of technologies and sounds a little confused, so I'll try to summarize these different technologies. [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) makes it possible for your Android app to register itself and for your server to broadcast messages to all registered devices. [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) allows you to create a web server that serves as a backend for  your Android app (or as a frontend web app) hosted on Google's cloud infrastructure. Google App Engine includes a feature called [Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) which simplifies writing a backend for Android by automating serialization/deserialization, authentication, and auto-generating an Android client library for invoking the backend functionality. [Google+ sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in) allows you to provide users of your application with the ability to sign into your application with their Google+ account. Google+ sign in on the web also makes it possible to provide an opportunity to install your Android app and to persist the sign-in on the installed app.